# Excel data rearranging into another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'd need to make excel copy/refer and restructure data from sheet 1 into sheet sheet 2.

Sheet1 has the following structure:

> week..........1.........1..................2...........2................3..........3 etc.
>   id...........text  A....text B.........text A......text B
>   30010......200......400..............10...........20
>   30011.......50.......150...............5............15

Now I'd need to make rearrange this data for sheet2 into this:

> week...........1...............2...............3.....etc
>    id
>    30010
>    Text A........200...........10..............
>    Text B........400...........20..............
>    30011
>    Text A........50..............5.............
>    Text B........150............15.............

Hopefully this illustrates the issue I haven't been able to tackle or to describe in words properly.

There are about a hundred lines (id's) that would need this sort of treatment.. thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use pivot table for this after you copy and paste your data with 'transpose'. Here are the steps:

1. copy your data
2. Paste as 'transpose'. You should now have headers of columns as
   week, id, '30010' and '30011'.
3. Insert > Pivot table into new sheet with data source as your newly
   pasted table.
4. Drag 'week' into column labels
5. Drag '30010' and '30011' into Values label (bottom right hand
   corner). You should notice there is a summation of values for both
   30010 and 30011 appearing in row label.
6. Drag 'id' into row label.
7. p.s. You can off the subtotals and grand totals. Highlight the pivot
   table and copy paste into excel as text, change the labels
   accordingly (eg. Row label -> Week ; 'Sum of 30010' -> '30010') as
   what your table requires.
8. insert a row below 'Week' and input 'ID'.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Tableau makes a plugin for Excel which can reshape data into a columnar format. It would put your data into four columns: ID, Week, (Text A/B), and the values in the table. I don't think it would get you exactly what you're looking for, but you could pivot Tableau's output until you have what you want.

http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/addin-reshaping-data-excel

Comment: Can you please explain how to use this plug-in in a way that solves the OP's question? Just throwing out software (even good software) is not what Super User is about.